# The type-specification operator is like down-casting in Object-Oriented languages?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I was going through the book Haskell Programming from First Principles and came across following code-snippet.

```hs
Prelude> fifteen = 15
Prelude> :t fifteen
fifteen :: Num a => a
Prelude> fifteenInt = fifteen :: Int
Prelude> fifteenDouble = fifteen :: Double
Prelude> :t fifteenInt
fifteenInt :: Int
Prelude> :t fifteenDouble
fifteenInt :: Double
```

Here, *Num* is the type-class that is like the base class in OO languages. What I mean is when I write a polymorphic function, I take a *type variable* that is constrained by *Num* type class. However, as seen above, casting `fifteen` as `Int` or `Double` works. Isn't it equivalent to down-casting in OO languages?

Wouldn't some more information (a bunch of `Double` type specific functions in this case) be required for me to be able to do that?

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not equivalent. Downcasting in OO is a *runtime* operation: you have a value whose concrete type you don't know, and you basically assert that it has some particular case – which is an error if it happens to be actually a different concrete type.

In Haskell, `::` isn't really an operator at all. It just adds extra information to the typechecker *at compile-time*. I.e. if it compiles at all, you can always be sure that it will actually work at runtime.

The reason it works at all is that `fifteen` has *no* concrete type. It's like a *template* / generic in OO languages. So when you add the `:: Double` constraint, the compiler can *then* pick what type is *instantiated* for `a`. And `Double` is ok because it is a member of the `Num` *typeclass*, but don't confuse a typeclass with an OO class: an OO class specifies one concrete type, which may however have *subtypes*. In Haskell, subtypes don't exist, and a class is more like an *interface* in OO languages. You can also think of a typeclass as a *set of types*, and `fifteen` has potentially all of the types in the `Num` class; which one of these is actually *used* can be chosen with a signature.

Answer (score 4):

Downcasting is not a good analogy. Rather, compare to generic functions.

Very roughly, you can pretend that your `fifteen` is a generic function

```
// pseudo code in OOP
A fifteen<A>()  where A : Num
```

When you use `fifteen :: Double` in Haskell, you tell the compiler that the result of the above function is `Double`, and that enables the compiler to "call" the above OOP function as `fifteen<Double>()`, inferring the generic argument.

With some extension on, GHC Haskell has a more direct way to choose the generic parameter, namely the type application `fifteen @Double`.

There is a difference between the two ways in that `... :: Double` specifies what is the return type, while `@Double` specifies what is the generic argument. In this `fifteen` case they are the same, but this is not always the case. For instance:

```
> list = [(15, True)]
> :t list
list :: Num a => [(a, Bool)]
```

Here, to choose `a = Double`, we need to write either `list :: [(Double, Bool)]` or `list @Double`.

Answer (score 0):

In the type `forall a. Num a => a`†, the `forall a` and `Num a` are *parameters* specified by the “caller”, that is, the place where the definition (`fifteen`) used. The type parameter is implicitly filled in with a type argument by GHC during type inference; the `Num` constraint becomes an extra parameter, a “dictionary” comprising a record of functions (`(+)`, `(-)`, `abs`, &c.) for a particular `Num` instance, and *which* `Num` dictionary to pass in is determined from the type. The type argument exists only at compile time, and the dictionary is then typically inlined to specialise the function and enable further optimisations, so neither of these parameters typically has any runtime representation.

So in `fifteen :: Double`, the compiler deduces that `a` must be *equal* to `Double`, giving `(a ~ Double, Num a) => a`, which is simplified first to `Num Double => Double`, then to simply `Double`, because the constraint `Num Double` is satisfied by the existence of an `instance Num Double` definition. There is no subtyping or runtime downcasting going on, only the solution of equality constraints, statically.

The type argument can also be specified explicitly with the `TypeApplications` syntax of `fifteen @Double`, typically written like `fifteen<Double>` in OO languages.

The inferred type of `fifteen` includes a `Num` constraint because the literal `15` is implicitly a call to something like `fromInteger (15 :: Integer)`‡. `fromInteger` has the type `Num a => Integer -> a` and is a method of the `Num` typeclass, so you can think of a literal as “partially applying” the `Integer` argument while leaving the `Num a` argument unspecified, then the caller decides which concrete type to supply for `a`, and the compiler inserts a call to the `fromInteger` function in the `Num` dictionary passed in for that type.

† `forall` quantifiers are typically implicit, but can be written explicitly with various extensions, such as `ExplicitForAll`, `ScopedTypeVariables`, and `RankNTypes`.

‡ I say “something like” because this abuses the notation `15 :: Integer` to denote a literal `Integer`, not circularly defined in terms of `fromInteger` again. (Else it would loop: `fromInteger 15` = `fromInteger (fromInteger 15)` = `fromInteger (fromInteger (fromInteger 15))`…) This desugaring can be “magic” because it’s a part of the language itself, not something defined within the language.